# Operator precedence or Maximal Munch Rule comes first for Unary Operators

Tags: java, operator-precedence, unary-operator

Here I am having the following piece of code:

```
int a,b,x;
a=b=1;
x=a+++b;
```

Now the value of `x` will be 2 as `a` is first being *post incremented* and then it is being added to `b`.

Following is the compiled byte code :

```
 0  iconst_1
 1  dup
 2  istore_2 [b]
 3  istore_1 [a]
 4  iload_1 [a]
 5  iinc 1 1 [a]
 8  iload_2 [b]
 9  iadd
10  istore_3 [x]
```

So the expression will be equivalent to `x = (a++) + b`.

Now the other expression `x=a++++b`, won't compile because of the *maximal munch rule*. It will become `x = (a++) ++ b` and hence compilation error.

Is the above behavior of `x=a+++b` because of the **precedence of the operator** ++ or because of **maximal munch rule**?

Comment: Because of maximal munch.

Comment: @devnull, Is it mentioned in JVM spec or in JLS, or do you have any explanation regarding this?

Comment: Shouldn't x be 3?  a=1, b=1, then you do (a++) + b = (1+1)+1 which is 3?

Comment: @CodeChimp `a++` increments `a` but returns its original value. `++a` would return incremented value.

Comment: @Zeeshan Yes, it's quoted in the spec.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  It's crazy how your mind forgets such subtle details.

Comment: "`a` is first being incremented and then it is been added to `b`". Have doubt, is this statement correct? `a` values will be first added with the value of `b` and the value of addition would be assigned to `x`. After that `a` will be incremented. Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from [Lexical Translations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the
>   result does not ultimately make a correct program while another
>   lexical translation would.
>
> > Thus, the input characters *a--b* are tokenized ([§3.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5)) as *a*, *--*, *b*,
> >     which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though
> >     the tokenization *a*, *-*, *-*, *b* could be part of a grammatically correct
> >     program.

This would explain why

```
x=a+++b
```

is parsed as

```
x=(a++)+b
```

On the other hand, `a++++b` is tokenized as *a++*, *++*, *b* which causes an error.

Comment: Hello downvoter, could you please leave a note so that the answer could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

The unary operator "++" is recognized only when there is a variable to the left of the "++".  When you write a+++b, the third plus is the binary operator "add", while the first operator (++) is "increment variable by 1".  When you write  "a++++" things fail because this is like writing `a<unary increment variable by 1> <add> <add>`  and there is a missing argument for the first  operator. The second pair of plus signs is not recognized as an "increment variable" because (a++) is not a variable.

Now interestingly, the Java compiler does currently requires white space to properly recognize

```
z = a++ + ++b;  // this works
z = a+++++b;    // this fails
```

As an old compiler writer, I would expect that both constructs should be syntactically evaluated as the same (recognizing the two unary operators ++ and ++

Answer (score 0):

Maximal munch is a rule that is used in the lexer, operator precedence in the parser, and the lexer runs conceptually before the parser.  Hence, `x=a+++b` is turned into `x=(a++)+b`because of the maximal munch rule, not operator precedence:

When the lexer sees `a+++b` is will turn this into tokens [identifier `a`] [double plus] [plus] [identifier `b`].  The [double plus] token is due to maximal munch (take the longest match, and `++` is longer than `+`).  The parser can then only turn this into (a++)+b regardless of operator precedence.